# What is the best way to get tight timing of a thread in c (pthreads)

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Ok so I have a thread that I need to run exactly every 10ms, but it takes a variable amount of processing time (for simplicity we can assume the processing time is less than 10ms). Small deviations in the timing will, over time, add up and become a problem.

This is my current solution. It seems clunky, but moreso I'm worried about the time it takes to run timeval_subtract causing my timing to be off.  Does anyone have a better solution?

This is for a library and I cannot use system resources like timers or clocks.

```
void mythread(void *ptr )
{
    struct timeval tv_being, tv_end;
    int usToSleep;

    while(1)
    {
        gettimeofday(&tv_begin)

        //do stuff

        //now determine how long to sleep so we wake up 10ms after previous wakeup

        gettimeofday(&tv_end)

        usToSleep = timeval_subtract(tv_begin, tv_end); //this will return 10ms minus the elapsed time

        usleep(usToSleep);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Does your system support real real-time scheduling policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're at the mercy of the granularity of the process scheduler you're using. 10ms is probably achievable but remember when sleeping that the operating system will not schedule it immediately when it is available to be woken up. If other processes are ahead of it they may be chosen to run instead so you may be delayed.

Your approach is a good (or as good) of an approximation as you can get.

If you require better scheduling you can look into compiling a Linux kernel with real time options enabled which will give you a finer scheduling granularity.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance that my way is okay. I am building a library that has to work across whatever platform and kernel our customers happen to be using with minimal modification, so customizing the kernel or using system level resources is not an option.

Comment: @BrandonYates Then this is as good as you can get in terms of approximation, I would actually make the wake up time a little less than the exact difference but overshooting it by a microsecond or so is not noticable.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will accumulate error over time - for example if the sleep runs long by 1ms once, then you'll never catch that back up.  The result will be that over a long period, you'll run your loop less times than if it ran once every 10ms.

To avoid this, call the time function once up-front, then calculate the future deadlines based on that.  Using `clock_gettime()` with the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock is preferable to `gettimeofday()`, because the latter is a realtime clock and is therefore affected when the administrator changes the system time.

For example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

void mythread(void *ptr )
{
    struct timespec deadline;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &deadline);

    while(1)
    {
        //do stuff

        /* Add 10ms to previous deadline */
        deadline.tv_nsec += 10000000;
        deadline.tv_sec += deadline.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
        deadline.tv_nsec %= 1000000000;
        /* Sleep until new deadline */
        while (clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &deadline, NULL) != 0)
            if (errno != EINTR) return;
    }

    return;
}
```

(On versions of glibc before 2.17, you'll need to link with `-lrt` to use the POSIX clock functions).

Comment: This solution seems so simple and straight forward. Are there any advantages using more complex solutions with timerfd or signals instead of your code? To be more specific, I'm looking for a solution to simulate audio file playback - I need to maintain reliable playback position with as little error accumulation as reasonably possible on a generic, non-realtime Linux Debian based system. Also I don't quite understand that `errno` condition - shouldn't it quit when the interrupt is received instead of when it's not?

Comment: @JustAMartin: Signals are fairly difficult to work with correctly.  The advantage to timerfd is that you can integrate it into a file descriptor based event loop rather than using a thread.  This solution should not accumulate any error, you will just get some jitter.  The errno condition is to re-enter the sleep if it returned early due to interruption by a signal, and to quit on any other error (because any other error is unexpected and indicates a logic error in the program).

Comment: OMG this solution is so simple and so efficient.... i used to deal with real time clock, signals and semaphores but your code is 10x efficient! CPU usage in my application (needing a tick every 0.5ms) is dropped from 10% to 1%!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a realtime signal (`SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX`), fired by a timer based on the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock, and a signal handler that posts a global semaphore.

`sem_post()` is async-signal-safe and can be reliably used in a signal handler. This is according to POSIX.1-2008, and can be made POSIX.1-1990 compatible; therefore, this should work fine on all operating systems (except for Windows, as usual).

The timed function itself calls

```
    while (sem_wait(&semaphore) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
        ;
```

or

```
    while (!sem_trywait(&semaphore))
        skipped++;

    while (sem_wait(&semaphore) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
        ;
```

to wait for the next tick to occur.

(The signal delivery will interrupt the `sem_wait()` call, unless the signal handler was installed with flag `SA_RESTART` set. With `SA_RESTART` set for all installed signal handlers in the process, `sem_wait(&semaphore);` alone would be enough.)

Here's why I personally prefer this method:

- Kernel (or C library, or threading library) maintains the interval.
  This way I don't need to call `gettimeofday()` or `clock_gettime()`, or calculate the proper duration for the sleep.
- Increasing the priority of the process gives smaller jitters even at higher CPU loads.
- I can use a single signal handler with multiple timers and different intervals.
  When the timer event is a signal, the signal handler will get a timer-specific value in `siginfo->si_value` (and `siginfo->si_code == SI_TIMER`).
- Thread pools, even dynamically resized thread pools, are trivial to create.
  Each thread in the pool simply calls `sem_wait()`, to trigger on the next interval tick.
- Overruns can be detected (`timer_getoverruns()`) easily.
- Ticks are queued, and multiple ticks ("lost ticks") can be trivially dequeued.
  (Use `while (sem_trywait(&semaphore) == 0) dequeued++;` before waiting on a semaphore.)
- In a multithreaded process, the kernel can use any of the process' threads to deliver the signal.
  In a multithreaded process it is likely that the kernel can find an idle thread it can use to deliver the signal immediately, instead of postponing it. (My understanding; not verified from kernel source!)

Note, however, that I/O latencies (high I/O or I/O to slow large devices) may cause large (occasional) jitter. This is however true for any timing method.

Here is an example program, `jitter.c`:

```
/* This is POSIX C. strsignal() is in 200809L, otherwise 199309L is okay. */
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t    interrupted = 0;

/* Interrupt handler. Just updates the above variable to match the signal number.
*/
static void interrupt_handler(int signum)
{
    interrupted = signum;
}

/* Install interrupt handler.
*/
static int interrupt_on(const int signum)
{
    struct sigaction    act;

    if (signum < 1 || signum > SIGRTMAX)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = interrupt_handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL))
        return errno;

    return 0;
}

static timer_t                  periodic_timer;
static struct itimerspec        periodic_interval;
static int                      periodic_signal = -1; /* Not installed */
static sem_t                    periodic_tick;

/* Periodic tick handler. Just posts the semaphore.
 * Note: sem_post() is async-signal-safe.
*/
static void periodic_signal_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == periodic_signal)
        sem_post(&periodic_tick);
}

/* Install periodic tick. Returns 0 if success, errno error code otherwise.
*/
static int periodic_start(const int signum, const double interval_seconds)
{
    struct sigaction    act;
    struct sigevent     event;

    /* Invalid signal number? Invalid interval? */
    if (signum < 1 || signum > SIGRTMAX || interval_seconds <= 0.0)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    /* Verify there is no periodic signal yet. */
    if (periodic_signal != -1)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    /* Initialize the semaphore. */
    if (sem_init(&periodic_tick, 0, 0))
        return errno;

    /* Define interval. */
    {
        long    s  = (long)interval_seconds;
        long    ns = (long)(1000000000.0 * (interval_seconds - (double)s));

        /* Overflow in seconds? */
        if (s < 0L)
            return errno = EINVAL;

        /* Make sure ns is within limits. */
        if (ns < 0L)
            ns = 0L;
        else if (ns > 999999999L)
            ns = 999999999L;

        /* Zero seconds maps to one nanosecond. */
        if (s == 0L && ns == 0L)
            ns = 1L;

        periodic_interval.it_interval.tv_sec = (time_t)s;
        periodic_interval.it_interval.tv_nsec = ns;
        periodic_interval.it_value = periodic_interval.it_interval;
    }

    /* Install signal handler. */
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = periodic_signal_handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;

    /* Describe the periodic event: it is a signal. */
    event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    event.sigev_signo = signum;
    event.sigev_value.sival_ptr = NULL;

    if (timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &event, &periodic_timer) == -1) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;

        /* Uninstall the signal handler. */
        act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
        act.sa_flags = 0;
        sigaction(signum, &act, NULL);

        /* Failed. */
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    /* Arm the timer. */
    if (timer_settime(periodic_timer, 0, &periodic_interval, NULL) == -1) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;

        /* Destroy the timer. */
        timer_delete(periodic_timer);

        /* Uninstall the signal handler. */
        act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
        act.sa_flags = 0;
        sigaction(signum, &act, NULL);

        /* Failed. */
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    /* Clear the overrun count. */
    timer_getoverrun(periodic_timer);

    /* Done. */
    periodic_signal = signum;
    return 0;
}

/* Uninstall periodic tick. Returns 0 if success, errno error code otherwise.
*/
static int periodic_stop(void)
{
    sigset_t                set, oldset;
    struct sigaction        action;
    const struct timespec   zerotimeout = { 0L, 0L };
    const int               signum = periodic_signal;

    /* Not installed? */
    if (signum == -1)
        return 0;

    /* Mark signal uninstalled. */
    periodic_signal = -1;

    /* Cancel the timer. This also disarms its interrupt. */
    timer_delete(periodic_timer);

    /* Create a signal set containing only the periodic signal. */
    if (sigemptyset(&set) || sigaddset(&set, signum))
        return errno;

    /* Block the periodic signal. */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, &oldset))
        return errno;

    /* Uninstall the signal handler. */
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &action, NULL)) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, NULL);
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    /* Dequeue all periodic signal interrupts. */
    while (sigtimedwait(&set, NULL, &zerotimeout) == signum) {
        /* Intentionally empty */
    }

    /* Restore the signal mask. */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, NULL))
        return errno;

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double          interval, output, duration, minduration, maxduration;
    unsigned long   limit, count = 0UL, skipped;
    struct timespec prev, curr;
    char            dummy;

    if (interrupt_on(SIGINT) || interrupt_on(SIGHUP) || interrupt_on(SIGTERM)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set interrupt handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s interval [ count ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "This program tests the timer interrupt jitter using semaphore wakeups.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Interval is in seconds. The program will exit after count intervals.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "You can also interrupt the program with an INT (Ctrl-C), HUP, or TERM signal.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[1], " %lf %c", &interval, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid interval in seconds.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    } else
    if (interval <= 0.0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Interval must be positive!\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc > 2) {
        if (sscanf(argv[2], " %lu %c", &limit, &dummy) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid number of interrupts.\n", argv[2]);
            return 1;
        }
    } else
        limit = ~0UL;

    if (periodic_start(SIGRTMIN+0, interval)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set up a periodic interrupt: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &curr);
    minduration = maxduration = interval;
    output = 0.0;
    skipped = 0UL;

    printf("Interval is %lu.%09ld seconds.\n",
           (unsigned long)periodic_interval.it_interval.tv_sec, periodic_interval.it_interval.tv_nsec);
    fflush(stdout);

    while (count++ < limit && !interrupted) {
        while (!sem_trywait(&periodic_tick))
            skipped++;

        /* Wait for next tick. */
        prev = curr;
        while (sem_wait(&periodic_tick) == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &curr);

        duration = difftime(curr.tv_sec, prev.tv_sec) + ((double)curr.tv_nsec - (double)prev.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
        if (duration < minduration) minduration = duration;
        if (duration > maxduration) maxduration = duration;

        output += duration;
        if (output >= 5.0) {
            printf("Jitter: %+9.06f .. %+9.06f milliseconds, skipped %lu ticks\n",
                   (minduration - interval) * 1000.0,
                   (maxduration - interval) * 1000.0,
                   skipped);
            fflush(stdout);

            minduration = maxduration = duration;
            output = 0.0;
            skipped = 0UL;
        }
    }

    if (output > 0.0)
        printf("Jitter: %+9.06f .. %+9.06f milliseconds, skipped %lu ticks\n",
               (minduration - interval) * 1000.0,
               (maxduration - interval) * 1000.0,
               skipped);
    fflush(stdout);

    periodic_stop();

    if (interrupted)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s.\n", strsignal(interrupted));
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Completed.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it using e.g.

```
gcc -W -Wall -O3 jitter.c -lrt -o jitter
```

and run without parameters to see the usage. It will output a jitter report every five seconds. My test results were obtained by running

```
./jitter 0.010
```

in one window on my workstation, doing other stuff, and looking at the output.

On a stock 64-bit Ubuntu 3.5.0-30-generic kernel on an AMD Athlon(tm) II x4 640 four-core processor, typical jitter is less than ±0.05 milliseconds (±50 µs) at low to medium loads, occasional peaks at ±0.20 milliseconds (±200 µs). At high loads, the jitter may reach a millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

use `gettimeofday()` at starting of thread storing the time

use `gettimeofday()` at the end of thread

calculate the difference = ONLY an estimate

`gettimeofday()` gives you time to microseconds, that is the tight you can get

**basic** usage:

```
void millitime(){/*secondsSinceEpoch*/
    struct timeval tv;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    printf("secs:%Ld usecs:%Ld \n",(unsigned long long)(tv.tv_sec),(unsigned long long)(tv.tv_usec));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

man gettimeofday

> CONFORMING TO
>
> POSIX.1-2008 marks gettimeofday() as obsolete, recommending the use of clock_get‐time(2) instead.

Also, you might want to run your test multiple times and keep the average elapsed time to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

http://widefox.pbworks.com/w/page/8042322/Scheduler

It is VERY hard to get a low-jitter 10ms process on a consumer OS.  The OS tends to time slice its work in units of that size or larger.  If the computer is choosing to use a 10ms timeslice, and there's three competing threads, you may be delayed by 30ms or more!

If you actually need to run reliably every 10ms (with some jtiter bound around that), you **must** use a real time opeating system.  Their entire purpose is to solve the problem you are tackling